# Partial jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I hope someone can help with a small jQuery-UI issue I have.

I've got two lists for which I allow drag and drop using jQuery UI sortable() and 'connectWith'. I need to limit this solution, by only allowing to reorder elements in one of the lists, and in the other always keep them alphabetically sorted.
Any idea how to achieve that?

I still want to be able to drag from A -> B and A <- B and also rearrange/sort the items in B, but I want A to stay sorted.

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to have two lists with elements being able to freely drag from one to another, but second list should always sort itself when it receives an element?

Comment: Correct. And also, that second list shouldn't allow drag-sorting of elements within itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sort elements in the second list upon "sortupdate" event:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pzfzU/)

```
$("#unsortable_list").on("sortupdate", "", function(event, ui) {
    var $list = $(this).children("li");
    $(this).append($list.sort(sortByHtml));
});
```

If one tries to reorganize elements in the second list - they will just bounce back to alphabetical order.

Pure dragging of elements in the second list should not be disabled, because one might want to drag them back to the first list.

Comment: that's almost what I wanted, but is there a way to disable the UI of the 'reordering' in the disabled list but leave the dragging to the first list?

Comment: I don't think it actually possible: to move an item from one list to another - user will have to start dragging it and you will not be able to find out his/her intentions on where he/she wants to drop it, until the item is actually dropped.